# Why there is an output difference between o.id(primary_key) and o.account_id(Foreign_key)?

Tags: sql

When I put those two different lines of code, they give me different outputs. Why is that? The purpose of the code is to find those companies that spent more per order than the average of all orders.

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

The schema is this:

[image]

Comment: Some account have more than one order.

Comment: Because `GROUP BY 1` is telling it to group by the first column so you are grouping by different columns.  These two columns have a different amount of distinct values in them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Just curious, when I tried to AVG(avg_amt) from those two tables generated, it actually gave me not exactly the same but very close numbers. If I didn't pay attention to those two different outputs, I would never even realize I was actually calculating two different things.  Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Your second query will be finding the amount per order, not per company. Using ordinal positions instead of column names is an anti-pattern best avoided - it's deprecated in some databases or not valid syntax; always reference columns by their name for clarity!